# Generic method works with different actual parameter

Tags: java, generics

Here I have a generic method which accepts a generic type parameter `T`

```
 public static <T> boolean compare(T p1, T p2) {
        return p1.equals(p2);
    }
```

now if I call this method like below

```
compare(10, "");
```

it works but as I assume it shouldn't work cause it can accept only one type of `Type parameter`, so how inference algorithm works here?

Comment: Can't you just print out the type of p1 and p2 inside the method?

Comment: @Takendarkk it print `java.land.Integer` for first parameter and for second it prints `java.lang.String`.

Comment: Interesting. I guess that is from `getClass().getName()`. I will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

It works because Integer and String have common parent: Object and you do not specify any constraint in type T. If you write:

```
public static <T extends Number> boolean compare(T p1, T p2) {
    return p1.equals(p2);
}
```

you get compile time error.

Answer (score 2):

The method call works because you haven't constrained the type `T` and since both `String` and `Integer` are sub-types of `java.lang.Object` that is that type that will be inferred.

Answer (score 0):

Your method will compile and not throw any exception at runtime.

The reasons are:

- [Type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) will prevent the JVM from knowing your parametrized type at runtime, and since you are not binding your parametrized type (e.g. `T extends CharSequence`, etc.), any `Object` and "boxable" primitive will compile as parameter during invocation
- Invoking `equals` on the parameters is tantamount to invoking `Object#equals` in this case, hence no runtime exception will be thrown. `false` will be returned as the references between your arguments are not equal

If you invoke your method with objects sharing the same reference, it will print `true`.

If you invoke your method with objects sharing the same value (e.g. two equal `String`s), it will return `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have a doubt what is the difference between `<? extends Object>` and `<T extends Object>`.

Comment: @eatSleepCode in this precise context, none technically, but one functionally. `?` is a wildcard for any type, while `T` is the definition of a type you can re-use, bounded or not by `extends...`. If you use `?`, you can't declare `T`s in your method argument list, body, or return type which will often limit your functionality.

Comment: Type erasure has nothing to do with it. If we had reified generics this would also work.

Comment: @newacct I haven't said type erasure is the cause of the behavior. It's a complementary piece of information here.

Comment: @Mena: It's not complementary. It's just completely irrelevant.